# Volume of $y=x^2$ bounded by $y=a$ with substraction

Tags: calculus, volume

I'm trying find the volume of the volume of $y=x^2$ rotated around the $y$ axis and bounded by $y=a$. I'm following MIT 18.01 and professor solves the problem by slicing the shape to shells. To be more exact $$y=x^2, y=a\\One \ slice = dV = (2\pi x)(a-x^2)dx\\V=\frac{\pi }{2} a^{2}$$
But I think there is an easier solution. Why don't we just calculate the volume of the cylinder with height $a$ and radius = $\sqrt{a}$ (as $y=x^2$) and subtract the area under the $y=x^2$ curve rotated around the y axis?$$y=x^2, y=a\\V_{cylinder} = \pi\cdot\sqrt{a}^2\cdot a=\pi\cdot a^2\\Area\ under\ x^2 =A_{curve}=\int ^{\sqrt{a}}_{0} x^{2} dx\\V_{curve}=A_{curve}\cdot2\pi\\V=V_{cylinder}-V_{curve}=\pi(a^2-\frac{2}{3}a^{3/2})$$Why they do not equal the same thing?

Comment: Althought the idea is nice, it is not well executed, because $V_{curve} = A_{curve}\cdot 2\pi$ is not quite correct.

Comment: @FormerMath Could you elaborate bit more on why it is not correct. Intuitively I thought that if I multiply area with the perimeter I would get the rotated volume.

Comment: A very simple argument could be the following: the rectangle of lenght 2 and height 1 gives different volume depending on the rotation axis. But they have the same area, so the formula can't be true.

Comment: That's reasonable, but still I can't explain it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you calculated $V_{\textrm{curve}}$ is incorrect. There is no such formula $V_{\textrm{curve}}=A_{\textrm{curve}}\cdot 2\pi$,

Instead, if you use the [shell method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration):
$$
V_{\textrm{curve}}=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{a}}2\pi x\cdot x^2\ dx=\frac{1}{2}\pi a^2
$$
so that
$$
V_{\textrm{cylinder}}-V_{\textrm{curve}}=\frac{1}{2}\pi a^2
$$

Comment: I got it. Then is my idea right?

Comment: @log101: Your idea is not right: "The way you calculated curve is incorrect."

Comment: I mean if you substract $V_{curve}$ from the cylinder you get the same result?

Comment: @log101: yes, that is correct.

Comment: Could you please explain why my intuition is wrong? When we calculate the volume of a cylinder we multiply base circle with height. So there are "height" pieces of circles on top of each other. In my calculation, there are $2\pi r\ V_{curve}$'s, so when I multiply I should get the same answer with the shell method?

Comment: @log101: $A_{curve}\cdot 2\pi$ is not an analog of "area of base times height".